# Proposal: inform <2k user who attempts <6 char edit that they need 2k to do it

Tags: feature-request, edits, character-limit

background:

- [Edit size requirement does not allow for significant syntax improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91008/)
- [pure code formatting, to enhance a question, is impossible (without 2k rep)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87200/)

I didn't know that a 2k user is able to make <6 char edits. This would be useful information. Maybe the error message should inform the user of this.

Comment: What does the error message say now? I was pretty sure that it said you aren't allowed to make edits under six characters...

Comment: Yes, but how would you know that you need to be >2k? Reading the text it comes out as nobody will ever be able to edit below 6 char. I just tried to edit the first answer of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162480/get-image-from-secured-web-service, by making sure the first line was a part of the code block, and my thought was that nobody could ever edit this post.