# Suggested tag wiki edit with no changes at all

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

There's a [pending tag wiki edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/118465) which actually makes no changes at all as far as I can make out. As far as I can see there's a bug somewhere, the side by side diffs show no change and the markdown diffs show no change either. (Shows 7 identical lines skipped). I can't see any `<!-- extra space -->` tricks there even. It's more extreme than [this similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80836/suggested-edits-with-0-changes) since I *can* see the space changes in that edit.

Is it a bug in the diff viewer not showing some change? The changelog says "changed 11 characters in the body". Why would anyone want to make an edit like that to a tag-wiki? Is it just cheating for the [tag-editor badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/73/tag-editor)? (Looks like it's [not the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/118464) they've tried this on a tag-wiki too)

Comment: The user got the tag-editor badge on 17 Feb 2011, so I doubt that's the motivation.

Comment: @JasonPlank - unless they believe it can be awarded multiple times perhaps

Comment: [Another occurrence.](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/220587)

Comment: [Related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125611/side-by-side-viewer-missing-from-suggested-edit-with-no-obvious-changes)