# Side-by-side viewer missing from suggested edit with no obvious changes

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suggested tag wiki edit with no changes at all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108890/suggested-tag-wiki-edit-with-no-changes-at-all)

[This suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/220587) shows only

> 4 identical lines skipped

Now [this happened before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108890/suggested-tag-wiki-edit-with-no-changes-at-all), but the problem now is that the side-by-side rendering option has disappeared too:

[image: No side-by-side rendering, only diff]

so there's no way for me to see any changes. (I'm tempted to reject as 'too minor' anyway.)

Snuck-in-feature-suggestion: could we have the 'identical lines skipped' clickable and become a whitespace-sensitive diff, or whatever's necessary to make it actually show some changes? As it stands there's no way for me to actually look at the mark-up here for a tag wiki edit, at least at my level of rep.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any case where one of these edits *wouldn't* be rejected by a reviewer?

It seems to me the best approach would be to just have the system auto-reject them.

Comment: Probably - or refuse to accept them as edits in the first place. (But I meant this question to be about the missing view-current-post button from the review interface.)

Comment: @Rup - Yeah, my intention wasn't to hijack your topic; I had kind of merged yours and your referenced (existing) question in my mind. If we auto-reject or disallow these types of edits, it's likely that both issues would be resolved, though.